# How to destroy VueJS component when router-link is clicked (router path does not change)

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-router

I need to refresh a component on the page once a user fills up the account opening form. I know that :key="$route.fullPath" will not help me because my router path doesn't change.

This is the container that holds the router-view.

```
<template>
  <section>
    <the-navbar class="mb-4"></the-navbar>
    <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
        <router-view></router-view>
    </transition>
  </section>
</template>
```

When a user clicks a button to open account, the following component is loaded. This component holds 2 child components - AccountOpenForm and AccountOpenConfirm. When a new account is opened, AccountOpenForm becomes hidden through the v-if directive and AccountOpenConfirm is shown instead.

What I need now is when the user clicks open account again, I need to fully reload the router view and display AccountOpenForm again. What's the best way to do that?

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <div class="mx-2 mt-8">
      <v-row>
        <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
          <account-open-form
            @create-account="createAccount"
            :overlay="overlay"
            v-if="!newAccount"
          >
          </account-open-form>
          <account-open-confirm
            :new-account="newAccount"
            v-else
          ></account-open-confirm>
        </transition>
      </v-row>
    </div>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `<component :is="comp">` ? `comp` would alternate between `open-confirm` and `open-form`. AFAIK, unless you're wrapping `<component>` with `kee-alive`, the components should completely reload.

Comment: I'm passing different props to each component, so I didn't try this option. I thought there could be another solution.